# Multiprocessing in a for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have the below `matching()` function with for loop to which I am passing a big `generator(unique_combinations)`.

It takes days to process so I wanted to use multiprocessing for elements in the loop to speed things up but I just can't figure out how to do it.

I find it difficult to understand the logic behind `concurrent.futures` in general.

```
    results = []
    match_score = []

    def matching():    
        for pair in unique_combinations:        
            if fuzz.ratio(pair[0], pair[1]) > 90:    
                results.append(pair)    
                match_score.append(fuzz.ratio(pair[0], pair[1]))

    def main():    
        executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)    
        task1 = executor.submit(matching)    
        task2 = executor.submit(matching)    
        task3 = executor.submit(matching)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()

print(results)
print(match_score)
```

I am assuming this should speed up the execution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using concurrent.futures, the nicest way, IMO, is to use map:

```
import concurrent.futures

def matching(pair):
    fuzz_ratio = fuzz.ratio(pair[0], pair[1])  # only calculate this once
    if fuzz_ratio  > 90:    
        return pair, fuzz_ratio
    else:
        return None


def main():
    unique_combinations = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        for result in executor.map(matching, unique_combinations, chunksize=100):
            if result:
                # handle the results somehow
                results.append(result[0])
                match_score.append(results[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There are lots of ways to handle the results but the gist is that you return a value from `matching` and then retrieve it in the `executor.map` for loop in `main`.  Docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).

Comment: Many thanks this is exactly what I needed.When I try to run the code however I am getting BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending. I have tried chaning to max_workers=1 but didnt help. Any ideas?

Comment: @cnns A google suggest that it may be because you didn't wrap your code in `main` and `if __name__...`.  It has something to do with how Windows forks processes (or cannot fork processes or something).